# My joining letter is delayed and HR is unresponsive. What should I do?

Tags: new-job, onboarding

So, my starting date mentioned in the offer letter is 8/17. My background check was completed on 8/4. I also completed my I9 form and Pre-employment documents. Its 8/13 day I don't have my joining letter, I tried to contact HR about the next step or when to expect joining letter but haven't received any response yet. What should I do?

Comment: Pick up the phone and call them?

Comment: How did you contact HR? That's pretty much the next step. You might also contact your hiring manager, if you've exhausted your options contacting HR.

Comment: Are you sure you need a "joining letter" ? In my neck of the woods, you just sign the offer letter and all other paperwork happens on the first day (or week) or work

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @PlayerOne the mention of an I9 form would imply United States.

Answer (score 9):

> What should I do?

If you haven't received any response via email, you should definitely give them a phone call.

A call is way more efficient in this scenario than waiting for an email reply.

Try starting with any phone contact you have obtained during the process (the recruiter that has been contacting you for example). If you have not obtained any phone contact in the email exchanges you've had, try looking for the company's number and call that, and ask to talk with the HR department.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the assumption of this being in the United States, there is not a requirement for a joining letter.

Once the background investigation was satisfied, and there were no other pre-conditions for employment such as a  drug test, or official transcript, then the I9 and the other pre-employment forms are a sign that you should report to work on the 17th of August.

They should also give you information that you need for that first day. This would include location, time, and POC for the first morning. Depending on the size and structure of the company, they may do all the day one activities at a central location. In other cases they do them at your worksite, or during COVID they may even do them by video.

They should also tell you what you need to bring that first day such as ID, birth certificate, banking information for direct deposit.

Reach out to anybody related to on-boarding. That could be the hiring manager, the recruiter, or the people who sent you the I9 and pre-employment forms. Use phone and email to try and contact them if you have any questions.